# Exception when opening Windows Work Flow Activity

Tags: visual-studio-2013, workflow-foundation

I am just getting started with windows work flow foundation but whenever I double click an activity in visual studio 2013, expecting the designer to appear i get the following exception.

```
  System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AssemblyCatalog.get_InnerCatalog()
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AssemblyCatalog.GetExports(ImportDefinition definition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.DirectoryCatalog.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetExports>b__2(ComposablePartCatalog catalog)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2.MoveNext()
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.InternalGetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.InnerCatalogExportProvider.GetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.TryGetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition, IEnumerable`1& exports)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.GetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.TryGetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition, IEnumerable`1& exports)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AggregateExportProvider.GetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.TryGetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition, IEnumerable`1& exports)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionContainer.GetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.TryGetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition, IEnumerable`1& exports)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExports(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExportsCore(Type type, Type metadataViewType, String contractName, ImportCardinality cardinality)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExportedValueCore[T](String contractName, ImportCardinality cardinality)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExportedValueOrDefault[T](String contractName)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExportedValueOrDefault[T]()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Activities.WorkflowDesignerExtensionManager.InternalGetExtension[T]()
```

Any Ideas of how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know the reason, but I advise you to have a look at the property that is mentioned in the exception message: LoaderExceptions.  So, put a breakpoint to inspect the exception and drill down to the LoadExceptions.  This is a collection, as far as I remember and in that collection, you will find one or more reasons for your exception.  
Maybe that will give you the details you need.  If not > you can post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my visual studio and included both LightSwitch and Microsoft Office Developer tools in the install, and that fixed it.

Comment: You mean LightSwitch extension and MS Office developer extension right?